# He considers it important to cooperate. vs. He considers it is important to cooperate

Tags: sentence-structure

I have a friend studying for an English test and she asked me to explain something to her.

In her textbook, the sentence

- "He considers it is important to cooperate." - is marked incorrect, while
- "He considers it important to cooperate." - is marked correct.

I would intuitively use the second "correct" sentence, but I can't explain why exactly. I have looked a bit here and elsewhere online but can't seem to find an answer.

I'd like to avoid telling her it's correct "just because" and instead give her a solid answer.

So why is it correct to get rid of "is" here?

Comment: As a native BrE speaker I would consider both are correct. "is " is optional and does not change the meaning of the sentence. **However** please edit the question and add why the textbook thinks it should be omitted. There must be some reason somewhere in the book.

Comment: I agree. Both are grammatically OK and have the same meaning, though the second is much more likely. Grammatically, the first has "(that) it is important to cooperate" as a declarative content clause serving as complement of "consider", while the second is an extraposition construction with "it" as direct object and the infinitival clause "to cooperate" functioning as extraposed object.

Comment: @PeterJennings thank you for the answer. I really appreciate it. To be honest, I haven't seen the actual textbook page and I can't speak to the quality of this book either. She just asked me the question through email and only gave me those two sentences and the information that the book marked one as correct and the other as incorrect.

Comment: @BillJ thank you for the answer. That's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> [1] *He considers* [*it is important to cooperate*].
>
> [2] *He considers it important* [*to cooperate*].

These are just two different ways of saying the same thing, though [2] is much more likely, probably because it is more economical since it uses less words to express the same meaning as [1].

Syntactically, in [1] the expression *it is important to cooperate* is a declarative content clause serving as complement of "consider".

[2], by contrast, is an 'extraposition' construction with *it* as direct object and the bracketed infinitival clause *to cooperate* functioning as extraposed object.

Answer (score 0):

I find it<sup>1</sup> interesting that [according to Google Books,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=consider%20it%20necessary%2Cconsider%20it%20is%20necessary%2Cthink%20it%20necessary%2Cthink%20it%20is%20necessary&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) 40 years ago *consider it necessary, think it necessary* and *think it **is** necessary* were all equally common. But *consider it **is** necessary* has always been extremely uncommon...

[image]

I can only assume the significant decline in use of ***is*** after ***think*** is because more people have started to apply the same idiomatic preference to ***think*** that they'd always applied to ***consider*** anyway.

As to why ***consider*** rarely occurs with a "tensed verb" clause, ***I think it's*** probably just that ***consider*** is a relatively "formal, upmarket" verb compared to the "everyday" verb ***think***.

Consequently, ***I consider it likely*** the relatively "literary"<sup>2</sup> construction illustrated by this very sentence was always much more closely associated with ***consider*** than with ***think***.

---

Obviously OP's friend's cited textbook should be thrown in the dustbin, since it erroneously conflates "idiomatically less common" and "syntactically invalid".

---

<sup>1</sup> Less commonly (but certainly not "unacceptably"), *I find it **is** interesting...* But *more* commonly (more "often" *and* more "colloquially") *I **think it's** interesting...*

<sup>2</sup> This type of construction is declining in English, but I think even though learners should normally avoid using it *themselves,* they probably do need to understand how it works. I won't go into details about it in this answer, but [here's what I wrote 10 years ago](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/59387/2637) on ELU.

Comment: I don't see what the subjunctive has to do with the OP's examples.

Comment: You're right (I'll probably go through and cross out all occurrences of the word). But I'm not much interested in such niceties of terminology anyway, as I'm sure you know. What matters is the actual words and constructions all native speakers actually say and write (even though most of them are like me; they don't know or care how *grammarians* describe things! :) But I will just say that I did manage to avoid mentioning "subjunctive" on [the same question on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/59387/2637)